# How to add two list of item same type in generic list in java

Tags: java

i have one method which accept `List<?>` i want to two list i want to add two list in single generic list  but i am unable to add i tried to create one generic type list but its not accepting.

I tried this:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(model.getfirstlist().getItems());                      
list.add(model.getSecondlist().getItems());
setListData(list)
```

My function is:

```
public void setListData(List<?> list) {
       // print list
}
```

getItems have field same field id, title

`setListData(model.getfirstlist().getItems())` // working fine

My function is like

```
public void setListData(List<?> list) {
       // print list
}
```

I am trying to add two list in single list and pass it into

```
singlelist = ( model.getfirstlist().getItems() +
model.getSecondlist().getItems())
setListData(singlelist);
```

Please suggest me how i will do this.

Comment: You want the [addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method of List.

Comment: yes @VGR we have two list with same type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method of Collection and List:

```
List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(model.getfirstlist().getItems());                      
list.addAll(model.getSecondlist().getItems());
setListData(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `List` that would contain as elements both lists:

e.g.

```
List<Integer> listA = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
List<Integer> listB = Arrays.asList(6,7,8,9);

List<List<Integer>> lists = Arrays.asList(listA, listB);
```

Then using streams api you could flatten the list you have created try the following:

```
List<Object> flattenList = Stream.of(lists)
                                 .flatMap(x -> x.stream())
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you **can't** use stream api you can try the following approach:

```
List<Integer> listA = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
List<Integer> listB = Arrays.asList(6,7,8,9);

listA.addAll(listB);
```

Now `listA` would contain also the items of `listB`.

Comment: Thanks for answer  let me try your answer.

Comment: we can  not use Stream   API there is some version issue with stream API   do you have any other solution .

Comment: @MARSH What version of Java you use ? Stream API  has been inserted in Java 8.

Comment: I am using java 8 but when i use this Android then there is some SDK version issue is coming  we cant go with Stream API

Comment: we have  not integer type we have Item type object.

Comment: @MARSH the above is an example. Since I don't know exactly what you have. Just try to call `addAll` on the first list and pass there the second list you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190852/discussion-between-marsh-and-christos).

Comment: model.getfirstlist().getItems().addAll(model.getSecondlist().getItems()) . i tried with this buts it show  setListData can not accept